# how can I get original avatar with socialite in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I work with socialite in laravel 5.6

with this

```
$social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
```

and with `dd($social_user)`

results:

```
User {#799 ▼
  +token: "517439085-SQzlrx8Op"
  +tokenSecret: "8KnMz1K5WQ9lpg"
  +id: "5176085"
  +nickname: "test"
  +name: "test"
  +email: "test@outlook.com"
  +avatar: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profilermal.jpeg"
  +user: array:40 [▶]
  +"avatar_original": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profileyxeYC5.jpeg"
}
```

I could get name, id and...

```
 $social_user->getName();
 $social_user->getAvatar();
 $social_user->getId();
```

But how can I get `avatar_original`?

Comment: show `dd($social_user->user)`

Comment: Note that the User Model field (ie: "avatar" attribute) must be fillable to be saved successfully to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [`avatar` and other properties are `public`](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/AbstractUser.php#L42), you can just access them using the standard syntax:

```
$social_user->avatar;
```

Comment: So the answer is : $social_user->avatar_original. thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Areza Google is not providing the original avatar, instead, it's giving a fixed 96*96 avatar, because, in mapUserToObject in the GoogleProvider Class, they are the same attribute for both avatar and avatar_original.